# How to use .schema.yml definition for two entities avoiding duplicated code

Tags: 8, configuration

What is the yml syntax in drupal .schema.yml files for specifying the same config for two entities? Something like this is what I need:

```
node.type.*.third_party.my_module:
media.type.*.third_party.my_module:
  type: mapping
  label: 'My Module'
  mapping:
    lots more lines here ...
    which I do not want to duplicate ...
```

I want the same settings for both `node.type.*` and `media.type.*` and there should be a way to avoid repeating all the definition and just having those two rows at the top.

Comment: I have tried a comma, semi-colon or just blanks, and tried the two on the same line. Can't find the right combination.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but this is what I'd try: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4255311/6335551

Comment: Thanks @sonfd yes that does work and is perfect for avoiding duplication. For clarity, and to help others, the definition of the alias has to be on the same line as the first key. However, when it used the second time it can be on a new line after the second key.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here is a very good way to do this, with thanks to @sonfd for the link.

```
node.type.*.third_party.my_module: &third_party_settings_alias
  type: mapping
  label: 'My Module'
  mapping:
    lots more lines here ...
    which I do not want to duplicate ... 

# Use saved alias to repeat the same settings for media.type
media.type.*.third_party.my_module:
  *third_party_settings_alias
```

That's all there is to it. All the settings for `node.type` are repeated for `media.type`

Comment: Further info: If you want to reuse the alias again, I found (strangely) that putting a comment line before the second reuse causes error ````Invalid data type in config my_module.schema, found in file modules/my_module/config/schema/my_module.schema.yml : Unable to parse at line 116 (near "*third_party_settings_alias"). in Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage->read() (line 118 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/FileStorage.php). ```` But removing the comment allows it to work just fine.